# Importing rt.jar is giving me dalvik error

Tags: java, swing, jar, dalvik

I am using `import javax.swing.JOptionPane` in my project and I need rt.jar for that since rt.jar contains `javax.swing`. But rt.jar is a runtime jar and I cannot add it because adding it gives me a dalvik error when I compile my project.

So is there any other way to solve this or get `javax.swing` from any other jar?

Answer (score 5):

Dalvik doesn't run un-modified Java classes. Dalvik is not Java!

And even if it did, Swing (or more precisely, the underlying AWT) has native components that need support from the JVM.

And even if that were not a problem, the classes in `rt.jar` are the classes that make up the Java platform implementation. You can't just swap out the `rt.jar` of one JVM with that of another one. They are tightly coupled with the JVM implementation.

Comment: I am not swapping out anything, i just need the swing components from rt.jar in my project to get rid of the errors like "JOptionPane cannot be resolved and the import javax.swing cannot be resolved" which it is getting rid off if i import rt.jar but it then gives a dalvik error which i cannot solve. O do i need to include anything else in the buildpath and if i do,how do i go about doing that /

Comment: Maybe I was being unclear: **you can't use Swing on Dalvik** (especially if this is on Android).

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run your project? Through an IDE such as Eclipse or command line? If you're doing through command line and need rt.jar to compile, your installation is toast!

If you're using Eclipse, you need to add a Java System Library to your project's build path.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I am doing it through Eclipse, since rt.jar consists of swing and awt that i need for my project, importing it gets rid of the errors in my project but gives me a dalvik error. I have all the other jars required. So how do i go about adding the Java system library to the build path ?

Comment: Thanks,the dalvik error's gone by adding the library. Have a whole different problem since the application's not working as i hoped :D

Comment: @Ronil, When I add JRE System Library[jdk1.6.0_05), my apk builds. However, the apk throws a runtime exception with the Android Emulator, The runtime exception says javax.ImageIO.ImageIO.read() method not found. Please advise me what to do to fix the avax.ImageIO.ImageIO.read() method not foound error. Thanks